# Select all rows having specific value assigned only once

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2014-express

I am confused that how i can query this from table below. I have to get only those categories which is assigned to a single group.

```
**Id**          **Category**   **PracticeGroup**
1               Category-1     Practice Group-1
2               Category-1     Practice Group-1
3               Category-2     Practice Group-2
4               Category-1     Practice Group-1
5               Category-2     Practice Group-1
```

As in above scenario Category-1 will be the result set which has only one assigned practice group "Practice Group-1".

Comment: Use an aggregate query : group by category, add COUNT(group), then add a filter such that COUNT(group) = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just can do this :-

```
select [category] from (select distinct [category] ,[Practice Group] from tbl) as temp
group by [category]
having count([category]) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to approach this type of question by comparing the minimum and maximum values:

```
select cateogry
from t
group by category
having min(practicegroup) = max(practicegroup);
```

Although `count(distinct)` can also be used, `count(distinct)` is much more expensive than simpler aggregation functions.  Also note that this ignores `null` values.  If you want to ensure that `null` values do not affect the results:

```
select cateogry
from t
group by category
having min(practicegroup) = max(practicegroup) and
       count(practicegroup) = count(*);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same query what @potasin mentioned, with the min of Practice Group

```
select [Category],min([Practice Group])
from tbl
group by [Category] 
having count(distinct [Practice Group]) = 1
```